# Umbraco 6 missing links & images

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco, umbraco6

I'm bit new to .NET / MVC and have a small problem with Umbraco CMS 6. After several months of usage Umbraco started removing links and images (which are listed) can not be seen in the media section even though they are still on the file system.

Any idea why this might happen? Maybe its a db issue and I can't seem to see it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It could be a caching issue. Try and republish the site or delete the umbraco.config in /app_data/ and recycle the the application

Comment: Anything in the suspicious in the log files?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the recycling bin in the media section to see if the media items have been deleted? It's possible that someone's deleted them in the CMS. You could also query the database directly to try and see if the data is still there.